# How to find out home directory of a user

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I created a FTP user a while ago. How can I find out his root directory?

**uname -a**

```
Linux linuxphp7 4.12.14-lp150.12.82-default #1 SMP Tue Nov 12 16:32:38 UTC 2019 (c939e24) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Not enough information. What do you mean by "root directory", and how did you create the user? What Unix are you running and how is "an FTP user" different from any other user on the system?

Comment: The term "root directory" is easily confused for "`/`", the root directory of a filesystem. Did you mean "home directory"?

Comment: The root directory is the home directory of a FTP user. After you log in to the FTP server with that user, then you land in that directory. Why does it mather how I created the user? I don't know this anymore, it is a long time ago.

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491877/how-to-find-a-users-home-directory-on-linux-or-unix#:~:text=To%20find%20the%20home%20directory%20for%20user%20FOO%20on%20a,the%20current%20user%2C%20use%20~%20.): echo ~username

Comment: Is the term "chroot" what you're thinking of? I've seen *that* in the context of vsftp. Just trying to find the correct terms, here.